# Sort json data into array of arrays by field

Tags: json, powershell

```
name        : SN608-ps-iLevel-C (74617)
total_bytes : 693123
sessions    : 30
planname    : Professional Plan Flexible Data
tags        : {All Island}
sms         : 0
usage       : {@{network_name=T-Mobile USA, Inc; bytes=693123; sessions=30}}name

SN523-ps-iLevel-C (02146)
total_bytes : 660570
sessions    : 31
planname    : Professional Plan Flexible Data
tags        : {All Island}
sms         : 0
usage       : {@{network_name=T-Mobile USA, Inc; bytes=660570; sessions=31}}


name        : SN517-ps-iLevel-C (01460)
total_bytes : 643331
sessions    : 29
planname    : Professional Plan Flexible Data
tags        : {Olympia Fuel}
sms         : 0
usage       : {@{network_name=T-Mobile USA, Inc; bytes=643331; sessions=29}}


name        : SN514-ps-iLevel-C (08713)
total_bytes : 364413
sessions    : 24
planname    : Professional Plan Flexible Data
tags        : {Olympia Fuel}
sms         : 0
usage       : {@{network_name=T-Mobile USA, Inc; bytes=364413; sessions=24}}
```

I want to generate a hashtable with `key = $_.tags` and `value = ($_.name, $_.total)bytes)` to look like

```
All Island (All Island SN608-ps-iLevel-C (74617) 693123,
            All Island SN523-ps-iLevel-C (02146) 660570)
Olympia Fuel (Olympia Fuel SN517-ps-iLevel-C (08713) 364413,
              Olympia Fuel SN514-ps-iLevel-C (08713) 364413)
```

This code does not work:

```
$response.data | ForEach-Object {
                $DeviceData = @($_.name, $_.usage.bytes)
                $BillData += @($_.tags, $DeviceData)
                }
                
                $BillData | Sort-Object { $_.tags }
```

Comment: Does `$response.data | Group Name,{$_.usage.bytes}|Select Name,Group` work?

Comment: Is what you show us the console print result from your JSON | ConvertFrom-Json? Please, can we have the actual json text in your post? (just click [edit] and put that in)

Comment: The ```tags``` property that you want to use as the key in your hashtable is an array of strings by the looks of things - what is the expected output if it's something like ```[ "mytag1", "mytag2" ]```? And is that treated as distinct from ```[ "mytag2", "mytag1" ]``` or do they need to get grouped together regardless of order?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure exactly what output you're after, but this seems like it's close:

First, define some test data:

```
$json = @"
{
  "data" : [
    {
      "name"        : "SN608-ps-iLevel-C (74617)",
      "total_bytes" : 693123,
      "sessions"    : 30,
      "planname"    : "Professional Plan Flexible Data",
      "tags"        : [ "All Island" ],
      "sms"         : 0,
      "usage": {
        "network_name" : "T-Mobile USA, Inc",
        "bytes"        : 693123,
        "sessions"     : 30
      }
    },
    {
      "name"        : "N523-ps-iLevel-C (02146)",
      "total_bytes" : 660570,
      "sessions"    : 31,
      "planname"    : "Professional Plan Flexible Data",
      "tags"        : [ "All Island" ],
      "sms"         : 0,
      "usage"       : {
        "network_name" : "T-Mobile USA, Inc",
        "bytes"        : 660570,
        "sessions"     : 31
      }
    },
    {
      "name"        : "SN517-ps-iLevel-C (01460)",
      "total_bytes" : 643331,
      "sessions"    : 29,
      "planname"    : "Professional Plan Flexible Data",
      "tags"        : [ "Olympia Fuel" ],
      "sms"         : 0,
      "usage"       : {
        "network_name" : "T-Mobile USA, Inc",
        "bytes"        : 643331,
        "sessions"     : 29
      }
    },
    {
      "name"        : "SN514-ps-iLevel-C (08713)",
      "total_bytes" : 364413,
      "sessions"    : 24,
      "planname"    : "Professional Plan Flexible Data",
      "tags"        : [ "Olympia Fuel" ],
      "sms"         : 0,
      "usage"       : {
        "network_name" : "T-Mobile USA, Inc",
        "bytes"        : 364413,
        "sessions"     : 24
      }
    }
  ]
}
"@

$response = $json | ConvertFrom-Json;
```

Then, group the entries using the first tag as the key:

```
$data `
  | select-object *, @{"n"="key";"e"={$_.tags[0]}} `
  | group-object -Property "key" `
  | sort-object -Property "Name" `
  | foreach-object `
      -Begin   { $result = [ordered] @{} } `
      -Process {
        $result[$_.Name] = @(
          $_.Group | select-object "name", @{"n"="usage_bytes";"e"={$_.usage.bytes}}
        )
      }

$result | ft

# Name         Value
# ----         -----
# All Island   {@{name=SN608-ps-iLevel-C (74617); usage_bytes=693123}, @{name=N523-ps-iLevel-C (0214...
# Olympia Fuel {@{name=SN517-ps-iLevel-C (01460); usage_bytes=643331}, @{name=SN514-ps-iLevel-C (087...
```

You might need to add some error handling for if there are zero tags for an entry, or more than one tag as you haven't described what should happen in those cases in your question, but this will hopefully be enough to get you started...

Answer (score 0):

Your own attempt is creating an *array*, whereas you say you want a *hashtable* (dictionary).

Given that you want output sorted by *keys*, you can use a [`` System.Collections.Generic.SortedList`2 ``](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Generic.SortedList-2) instead, which, after it has been filled from the JSON data, automatically outputs its entries in key sort order:

```
$sortedList = [System.Collections.Generic.SortedList[string, array]]::new()

$response.data | ForEach-Object {
   $sortedList[[string] $_.tags] += $_.Name, $_.total_bytes
}

$sortedList # output
```

Note:

- The sorted list uses case-*sensitive* lookups for keys by default; if you want case-*insensitive* behavior (as you get by default with PowerShell's [hashtables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables)), pass `[System.StringComparer]::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` to the `::new()` call.
- It looks like the `.tags` property contains an *array*, though the sample data shows only *one* value; the above simply converts that to a single string value; if *multiple* values are present, they are *joined with spaces* to form the key.

  - As [mclayton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3156906/mclayton) points out, this can create *ambiguity*; e.g., tag values 
    `'one', 'trick pony'` and `'one trick', 'pony'` would both result in the *same* key, `'one trick pony'`.
  - Also note the need for an explicit `[string]` cast, even though PowerShell normally *implicitly* stringifies arrays by joining their (stringified) elements with spaces; in fact, it does so on *creating* an entry, but not on *looking it up*: in the latter case, the array's elements are looked up *individually*. Again, tip of the hat to mclayton, who posted code to illustrate the problem [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/18779#issuecomment-1348958160).
- I'm using `$_.total_bytes`, not `$_.usage.bytes` (the latter is what you used in your own coding attempt), because your description and the sample output suggest the former - adjust as needed.

Comment: Indeed, @mclayton. It's an unfortunate asymmetry, and I'm not sure there's a good solution other than to _document_ the pitfall. Thanks for your help. I've deleted my other comments, and I suggest we clean up all of them here (the relevant info is now  in the answer).